# C# throw statement redundant?

Tags: c#, java, exception

I have a code that looks like this (sorry for the Java bracket style):

```
class SomeClass {
   public static void doSomethingRisky() {
        try {
          SomeRiskyFunction();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          throw e;
        }
   }
}

class MainClass {
   public void callSomethingRisky() {
        try {
          SomeClass.doSomethingRisky();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          FinallyHandleTheException(e);
        }
   }
}
```

Basically, `SomeClass` will be a library and I want to design it so that all exceptions will be handled by the calling program (who may or may not choose to display a message about the exception).

My question is about the use of `try/catch&throw` in the `doSomethingRisky()` from `SomeClass`. Is it redundant or is it necessary? I mean, if I leave it off and the function does encounter an Exception during runtime, will it crash the program because nothing catches the Exception inside THAT function, or does it still pass it to the caller (`callSomethingRisky()`) where it is gracefully handled?

Same question for Java. Thanks!

Comment: if you merele rethrow the exception in your catch block you may as well omit it completely

Comment: Dont catch an exception if you dont do something useful with it. At least use `throw;` instead of `throw ex;` in C# to keep the stack trace. Otherwiseit would look like the exception was raised at `doSomethingRisky` instead of `SomeRiskyFunction`.

Comment: Uhm.. I think, not sure, that you must throw the Exception in `public static void doSomethingRisky()` so you should remove the `try-catch` 'cause you lose stacktrace. Apologize me if I am not correct.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `try`/`catch` with `throw e;` in `doSomethingRisky` does exactly one thing: it destroys the stack-trace information. That ***probably*** isn't what you wanted, so the `try`/`catch` should be removed - it will already bubble-up as expected.

For info, if it was just `throw;` (rather than `throw e;`) then it would merely be redundant, rather than destructive.

Comment: Alternatively just use `throw` instead of `throw e`. It will rethrow the Exception without destroying the stack trace, just as like it wasn't catched at all.

Comment: @JustAnotherUserYouMayKnow indeed, I was editing that in while you commented

Comment: and what exactly does `throw;` throw?

Comment: @BogdanAlexandru it re-throws the original exception without altering it

Comment: thanks! that actually helped me understand these basic things

Answer (score 4):

It will pass to the caller in both ways.
One of the uses of the construct you show above is to log the exception in the procedure, but still throw it so somewhere up the call stack a `catch` can handle the exception.

One thing to keep in mind, use `throw` in this situation instead of `throw e` to avoid loosing stack trace information.

Answer (score 2):

In your case it is redundant.  Often developers will add more information to the exception, or create a new exception with the original exception embedded as an inner exception.  But to simply catch and rethrow is redundant.